# "Warning: multi-character character constant" when I used a C pointer

Tags: c, if-statement, pointers, warnings

Here is a fraction of a function I wrote to print a sentence once someone inputs "time". But when I compiled it, it said "Warning: multi-character character constant". I tried to use double quotes and it said "Warning: comparison between pointer and integers". Now, I'm very confused. Could you help me? Thanks!!!

```
char *status; 
scanf("%s", status);
if (*status == 'time')`
    {
        printf("The time of the meet-up is 4 p.m.");
    }
```

Comment: You've packed alot of errors into that short bit of code. 1. `status` is an uninitialised pointer and you can't write to it with `scanf`. Declare as an array `char status[64]` or dynamically allocate with `malloc`. 2. `'` is for characters and `"` for strings. So should be `"time"` 3. `==` is not how strings are compared in C. Use `strcmp(status, "time") == 0`.

Comment: You are very confused because you are probably used to programming in other languages than C. You misunderstand that `status` is automatically assigned memory when using `scanf`. That does not happen. Also, you must use double quotes for strings. You compare strings using `strcmp`, you cannot use the `==` operator for this. Learn C from the basics, not by assuming it will work similarly to e.g. Python.

Comment: Suggest you pause coding and go through a good C book or tutorial.

Comment: Did you look at other questions with the same warnings?

Comment: You also have a backtick character at the end of this line `if (*status == 'time')\`` but yeah I agree with @kaylum you need to take the time to properly learn C instead of just winging it

Answer (score 1):

**Some help**

`status` is not initialized.  The pointer value is indeterminate.  Consider an array of `char` instead.

```
char *status;
```

Passing an indeterminate value to `scanf()` is not good.  Using `"%s"` without a width limit is *bad*.  Use `fgets()` or a width limit.

```
scanf("%s", status);
```

`'time'` is not a *stirng*.  Much more likely you want `”time”`.  `==` here compares pointers.  To compare string content, research  `strcmp()`.

```
if (*status == 'time')`
```

Better to append a `’\n’` to the output.

```
    {
        printf("The time of the meet-up is 4 p.m.");
    }
```